# DB connection error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432?

Tags: postgresql, docker, npm

Running a docker container with postgres and npm produces this error, while running them separetly
(npm and docker) doesn't. What seems to be the error here?

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  db:
   image: postgres:12.1
   ports:
    - 5432:5432
   environment:
    - FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/
    - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass
    - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
   volumes:
    - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  migrate:
    image: boxfuse/flyway
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "/flyway/wait-for.sh db:5432 -- flyway migrate"]
    depends_on:
    - db
    volumes:
    - ./common/migrations/:/flyway/sql:rw
    - ./common/scripts/wait-for.sh:/flyway/wait-for.sh:rw
    environment:
#    - FLYWAY_LOCATIONS=classpath:/common/migrations/
    - FLYWAY_PASSWORD=mypass
    - FLYWAY_USER=myuser
    - FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/mydb?user=myuser&amp;password=mypass
    - FLYWAY_CONNECT_RETRIES=30

networks:
  default:
    name: mydb-local

services:
  example-service:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm start
```

Thing I have checked:

postgresql.conf & pg_hba.conf accepts connections.

DB credentials are correct.

Db is running

Comment: While the containers are running, can you exec into the migrate instance and try to ping db? It seems like it isn't resolving to the postgres instance, but to itself.

Comment: DB status is: ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2020-02-27 12:07:23 UTC; 36min ago
  Process: 6372 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6372 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Comment: Also, why do you have two services sections? Why not put them all in one?

Comment: Fixed to single service. How do i get docker-compose run nmp start properly? 
This line "command: npm start" produces "npm not found error"

Comment: That should be in the Dockerfile.